# Populate table column from code foreach row

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I recently started the transition from asp.net webforms to blazor server side.
I am still reading and learning about it, and as a side project in order to learn, i started to rewrite an application i made in webforms.

So, in the webforms, when i had to present very big amounts of data coming from ms sql server, i used asp:repeater to populate the main values, and then with nested update panels i managed to have the basic results almost instantly, and after 1-2 seconds, the other columns were populated.

I try to do something similar with Blazor, but with no luck at all.

My code for the main values is

```
   <tbody>        
            @if(antists==null)
            {
            }
            else
            {
                @foreach (var antist in antists)
                {                
                
                string? trdr = "405";
                string? mtrl = antist.Mtrl;
                string? trdbusiness = "2001";
                string? mtrpcategory = antist.Mtrpcategory;
                string? mtrmanfctr = antist.Mtrmanfctr;
                string image = "https://zerog01.b-cdn.net/" + antist.Image_guid + ".jpg";
                //getfldasync(trdr, mtrl, trdbusiness, mtrpcategory, mtrmanfctr);
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: center">
                        <a data-fancybox href=@image>
                        <img  id="img_eikona_in" runat="server" class="img-fluid" style="max-height:100px;"
                        src=@image onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='/webimages/no-image.jpg'" /></a>
                    </td>
                    
                    <td>@antist.Code.ToString() <br>
                    @antist.Name</td>                    
                    <td>@fld</td>  
               </tr>
                }
              }      
    </tbody>
```

My goal is to populate @fld from a stored procedure. If i use code to do this on the fly as the rows are being created, it is very slow. (same problem as webforms)

I tried to use async method, but no luck. The closer i got was to have `` System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String] `` shown in the column of @fld. I didn't keep the exact code, but it was something like

```
public async Task<string> getfldasync(string trdr, string mtrl, string trdbusiness, string mtrpcategory, string mtrmanfctr )
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con_digi);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@trdr", trdr);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mtrl", mtrl);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@trdbusiness", trdbusiness);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mtrpcategory", mtrpcategory);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mtrmanfctr", mtrmanfctr);
        await con_digi.OpenAsync();        
        var scalar = cmd.ExecuteScalarAsync();
        fld = Convert.ToString(scalar);
        await con_digi.CloseAsync();
        return fld;

>not a sp, but i wanted to make changes in order to test the code.
```

Is there another method i miss for presenting that kind of data? Or should i keep on trying to make async call?

Edit: I uploaded the code where i used datatable instead of list for the initial databind of the table.

Comment: *when i had to present very big amounts of data* - I'd say this is where the error is. What is a user realistically going to do with a webpage that has an X-thousand-row table on? Perhaps look at paging, or gradual loading of data; if each result takes a second to load, load 100 placeholders then fill them in asyncronously at a rate of one a second etc

Comment: You are right about this, i meant complex data. I tried to approach this by filling the data async, but I am getting all type of errors

Comment: What is "complex data"?

Comment: user inputs a search string. The output should be a list of products, with prices, description and characteristics. The list of products with the description is what i call "basic data". Then, based on users id, and productid, i want to execute a stored procedure to fetch the other columns. When i do this in one block, it works, but the load time is bad. I tried to use async to fetch the extra data, but no luck.

Comment: You are trying to build everything in the UI.  If I read you code correctly you are executing a Stored Procedure call for every loop through `antists`.  That is going to be slow.  You need to rethink your design.  Get your data and it's management out of the UI and into Services.  Apply async coding practices to your database access.  Providing a detailed answer that addresses all this is beyond the scope of a SO answer.

Comment: *Then, based on users id, and productid, i want to execute a stored procedure to fetch the other columns.* - I didn't quite undertand this bit; do you have some more itelligent/trained users that see a "power UI" and others that see a dumbed-down one? If so I'd consider having a viewmodel that could hold all data, but leaving most of it null if it's a dumb user logged in, and retrieve all the data in one hit (by all, i mean paginated or TOP N; if the user doesn't find what they want, they need to better specify their search terms) be that the limited set of dumb data or the full set..